# Are these theorems the same?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying adjoint operators from [Schaum's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071794565) book and I'm confused with these theorems:

[image]

So the author proves the conjugate transpose $B^*$ is the adjoint of $B$.

But some lines after, he states in part (II):

[image]

So in the first theorem he doesn't mention basis at all, then he says he have to have orthonormal basis and restate the same theorem, I'm confused.

So my question is, what's the difference between these two theorems?

I need help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many choices of a basis. The linear operator's matrix representation depends on its domain and range's choice of basis for which the representation is respect to, but the operator itself is the same regardless of the choice of basis.

The first result is for the standard inner product, the second theorem holds for any inner product (which determines the notion of orthonormality for a basis). So, the second one is more general than the first.

Comment: thank you for your answer!